# C# Method to Check if a String Contains Certain Letters

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a method which takes two parameters, "word" and "input". The aim of the method is to print any word where all of its characters can be found in "input" no more than once (this is why the character is removed if a letter is found).

Not all the letters from "input" must be in "word" - eg, for input = "cacten" and word = "ace", word would be printed, but if word = "aced" then it would not.

However, when I run the program it produces unexpected results (words being longer than "input", containing letters not found in "input"), and have coded the solution several ways all with the same outcome. This has stumped me for hours and I cannot work out what's going wrong. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated, thanks. My full code for the method is written below.

```
    static void Program(string input, string word)
    {
        int letters = 0;
        List<string> remaining = new List<string>();

        foreach (char item in input)
        {
            remaining.Add(item.ToString());
        }

        input = remaining.ToString();

        foreach (char letter in word)
        {
            string c = letter.ToString();

            if (input.Contains(c))
            {
                letters++;
                remaining.Remove(c);
                input = remaining.ToString();
            }
        }

        if (letters == word.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't `remaining.ToString()` give you something like `System.Collections.Generic.List\`1`? The debugger should tell you that.

Comment: Yes this was the problem, it was then searching for any of the characters in the string "System.Collections.Generic.List", thanks for the quick reply :)

Comment: Also I've noticed that you get unexpected results if you have repeated letters in a word. As Remove will remove all instances in your collection. So if you use 'TESTING' and 'TEST' you wont get the expected results

Comment: Is there any way to remove only one instance of an item from the list?

Answer (score 2):

Ok so just to go through where you are going wrong.

Firstly when you assign `remaining.ToString()` to your input variable. What you actually assign is this `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]`. Doing to ToString on a List just gives you the the type of list it is. It doesnt join all your characters back up. Thats probably the main thing that is casuing you issues.

Also you are forcing everything into string types and really you don't need to a lot of the time, because string already implements IEnumerable you can get your string as a list of chars by just doing `myString.ToList()`
So there is no need for this:

```
 foreach (char item in input)
 {
    remaining.Add(item.ToString());
 }
```

things like string.Contains have overloads that take chars so again no need for making things string here:

```
foreach (char letter in word)
{
    string c = letter.ToString();

    if (input.Contains(c))
    {
        letters++;
        remaining.Remove(c);
        input = remaining.ToString();
    }
}
```

you can just user the letter variable of type char and pass that into contains and beacuse remaining is now a `List<char>` you can remove a char from it.

again Don't reassign remaining.ToString() back into input. use string.Join like this

```
string.Join(string.empty,remaining);
```

As someone else has posted there is a probably better ways of doing this, but I hope that what I've put here helps you understand what was going wrong and will help you learn

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Regular Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) which was created for such scenarios.

```
bool IsMatch(string input, string word)
{
    var pattern = string.Format("\\b[{0}]+\\b", input);
    var r = new Regex(pattern);
    return r.IsMatch(word);
}
```

I created a sample code for you on [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RVg4hn).

You can check what the pattern does at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KqP2h4/1). It has a pretty "Explanation" and "Quick Reference" panel.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to achieve that, here is a suggestion:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Func("cacten","ace");
    Func("cacten", "aced");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void Func(string input, string word)
{
    bool isMatch = true;
    foreach (Char s in word)
    {
        if (!input.Contains(s.ToString()))
        {

            isMatch = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    // success
    if (isMatch)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(word);
    }
    // no match
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No Match");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I realised the problem wasn't in searching for the characters, rather the return from the List.ToString() method was not what I expected it would be

Answer (score 0):

Not really  an answer to your question but its always fun to do this sort of thing with Linq:

```
static void Print(string input, string word)
{
    if (word.All(ch => input.Contains(ch) &&
        word.GroupBy(c => c)
            .All(g => g.Count() <= input.Count(c => c == g.Key))))
        Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Functional programming is all about *what* you want without all the pesky loops, ifs and what nots... Notice that this code does what you'd do in your head without needing to painfully specify step by step how you'd actually do it:

1. Make sure all characters in `word` are in `input`.
2. Make sure all characters in `word` are used at most as many times as they are present in `input`.

Still, getting the basics right is a must, posted this answer as additional info.